# StructureMap 4 hiding real exceptions - how do I make it throw the correct ones?

Tags: c#, dependency-injection, structuremap

I have a web project containing 3 layers: Web (MVC5), BusinessLayer, DataAccess. I use StructureMap 4, Structuremap.MVC5 and StructureMap.WebApi2 to provide the default IoC configuration.

This is my configuration:

```
public static class IoC {
        public static IContainer Initialize() {
            var container = new Container(c => c.AddRegistry<DefaultRegistry>());
            return container;
        }
    }


public class DefaultRegistry : Registry {
        public DefaultRegistry() {
            this.IncludeRegistry<DataAccessLayerRegistry>();
            this.IncludeRegistry<BusinessLayerRegistry>();

            Scan(
                scan => {
                    scan.TheCallingAssembly();
                    scan.WithDefaultConventions();
                    scan.With(new ControllerConvention());
                });
        }
    }
```

The DataAccessLayerRegistry and BusinessLayerRegistry don't really do anything apart from scanning their respective dlls with DefaultConventions

Everything else is as generated by templates.

I inject dependencies in such hierarchical way:

Web:

```
public class HomeController : Controller
{
    private ITestClass _myTest;

    public HomeController(ITestClass testClass)
    {
        _myTest = testClass;
    }
}
```

BusinessLayer:

```
public class TestClass : ITestClass
{
    public TestClass(ITestValueRepository repo)
    {
    }
}
```

DataAccess:

```
public class TestValueRepository : ITestValueRepository
{
    IMyContext _dbContext;

    public TestValueRepository(IMyContext dbContext)
    {
        _dbContext = dbContext;
    }
}
```

This all works fine and the dependencies are resolved correctly but when there is an error in one of the constructors somewhere down the road, for example an error creating the IMyContext instance (which is an EntityFramework DbContext), I don't get to see the real exception that happened there (for example issue with EF configuration). Instead this is what I see:

> No parameterless constructor defined for this object.
>
> [InvalidOperationException: An error occurred when trying to create a
>   controller of type 'XXX.Web.Controllers.HomeController'. Make sure
>   that the controller has a parameterless public constructor.]

There is no inner exception nor additional stack trace info that could lead to the real problem. Why is StructureMap hiding the real exception? Is there any way that I can set the StructureMap configuration to make it throw the real exceptions?

Comment: The error (being thrown from MVC) indicates that you have not setup dependency injection to work with MVC. It has nothing to do with StructureMap, you have not enabled MVC to work with StructureMap. Please post your DI setup configuration, as the problem no doubt is there.

Comment: Not really, @NightOwl888 . If I go and fix the problem at the very bottom that causes issue in MyContext's constructor (without changing any Structuremap configuration at all) it suddenly starts working. My issue is that when there is an exception somewhere at the bottom this exception does not show at the top. It seems that Structuremap just catches it and instead of showing it to me, tries to use a nonexisting constructor at the top.

Comment: You have not provided a [Minimal, Complete, and Verifyable Example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve), which means you have not posted enough code for anyone else to reproduce the issue. I don't see how you expect this to be resolved unless you post your startup code and relevant StructureMap config.

Comment: @NightOwl888, I added my configuration. Practically everything I have is exactly as generated by templates of the NuGet packages I use. The dependency does work. The only issue I have is that when there is an Exception not related to Structuremap that happens in one of the constructors near the bottom, e.g. TestValueRepository, I don't see the correct exception at the top. Structuremap just hides it from me with the exception I pasted above.

Comment: @JakubRusilko Did you debug the code when the exception is thrown, and made sure it is thrown **from inside the constructor**? What exactly makes it throw in the constructor?

Comment: @shay__ Yes, I actually had to change this code a bit and introduce try/catch to be able to catch the exception. It turned out that my EntityFramework config was broken and IMyContext implementation could not be created. When I fixed the issue with EF everything started working ok. However, the problem is that I actually had to do the code changes and debug in order to find out what the real problem was. Instead I'd like Structuremap to give me this exception instead of hiding it.

Comment: @JakubRusilko if Structuremap catches the exception and throws another one instead, obviously there's nothing you can do to get the "original" exception (at least not in a conventional way). Although it looks more like Structuremap bug - it should have saved the original exception as an inner exception.